# Single admin, use roles and session?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've built a "CRUD" page where it should be one admin only.
I got my admin section in http://example/Admin/action/id, as a singel controller (perhaps not the best way to do it).
But my thought was to use a session and some roles that i put in the Admin controller.
What do you think, is that a good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to security you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Using asp.net membership provider will suits for sure. Maybe some customization of membership provider to fit your needs.

You can create roles and assign them to user and after that you can secure pages using decorated [Authorize] attributes or secure for selected users like this

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
```

Comment: Up and running as I whant. But im woundering how it will be on a publish. Will the user and the role be publish as well. Or is that only local?

Comment: @DavidLarsson not really sure what you mean by "Will the user and the role be publish as well". With Authorize attribute on action controller you can restrict access to the specific action inside controller or if you put this authorize attribute on top of class you restrict access to all actions inside that controller.